# Bounded wildcards not compiling

Tags: java, generics

I have code like this:

```
interface InterfaceA { ... }

interface InterfaceB { ... }

class ClassA {
    public void methodA(Class<? extends InterfaceB> clazz) { ... }
}

class ClassB<P extends InterfaceA & InterfaceB> {
    public void methodB(P p) {
        new ClassA().methodA(p.getClass());
    }
}
```

Question is: why compiler doesn't allow to pass `p.getClass()` as an argument to the method `methodA` - error mesage is:

```
The method methodB(Class<? extends InterfaceB>) in the type ClassA is not applicable for the arguments (Class<capture#1-of ? extends InterfaceA>)
```

It's clear that type `P` extends `InterfaceB` in `ClassB` so I have no idea why it's not working.

Comment: You could probably work around it by writing `p.getClass().asSubclass(InterfaceB.class)`, for what it's worth.

Comment: good example where erasure is unnecessarily harsh.  the compile-time could adopt a better, more accurate erasure. but JLS has only one type of erasure that applies to both compile and run time.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The return type of [`Object#getClass()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#getClass%28%29) is

> The actual result type is `Class<? extends |X|>` where `|X|` is the
>   erasure of the static type of the expression on which `getClass` is
>   called.

The erasure of the static type of `p` (the expression on which `getClass` is called) is the erasure of

```
P extends InterfaceA & InterfaceB
```

which is `InterfaceA`. This is specified in the Java Language Specification chapter concerning [Type Erasure](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-4.html#jls-4.6)

> The erasure of a type variable (§4.4) is the erasure of its leftmost bound.

Your method accepts a `Class<? extends InterfaceB>`, not a `Class<? extends InterfaceA>`. That's why your sample doesn't compile.

You can reorder your bounds to make *this* example work

```
class ClassB<P extends InterfaceB & InterfaceA> {
```